# Images not Showing Properly in Recycler View

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-image

I'm facing a problem with my Recycler View , Images are not showing properly,

Here is the links where you can see what i'm taking about

1. https://ibb.co/jXgXU9
2. https://ibb.co/ceTCU9
3. https://ibb.co/jkFsU9
4. https://ibb.co/jkFsU9
5. https://ibb.co/ffte99

when changing Recycler view **width** to match-parent and **height** to wrap_content it works but on scrolling down then coming back up it screws up and again only one images shows at a time

1. Here is code for customlayout.xml

   ```
     <LinearLayout
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content">


      <ImageView
          android:id="@+id/listicon"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="220dp" />

      </LinearLayout>
   ```

   2. Here is my fragment_home.xml

      ```
      <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      tools:context=".HomeFragment">
      <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
         android:id="@+id/drawerList"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
         android:layout_alignParentLeft="true">

         </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

          </FrameLayout>
      ```

3.Here is HomeFragment.java

```
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
    import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.ListView;
    import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.List;
    public class HomeFragment extends Fragment  {
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";
    private CustomAdapter adapter;
    int[] IMAGES = {R.drawable.abs,R.drawable.arms,R.drawable.back,R.drawable.chest,R.drawable.full,R.drawable.legs};
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;


    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;


    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;


    public HomeFragment() {

      }
    public static HomeFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {                   
    HomeFragment fragment = new HomeFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
        }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
        mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
    }
        }
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
     recyclerView =(RecyclerView) layout.findViewById(R.id.drawerList);
     adapter = new CustomAdapter(getActivity(), getData());
     recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
     recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    return layout;
      }

    public static List<Information> getData(){
    List<Information> data = new ArrayList<>();
    int [] icons = {R.drawable.abs,R.drawable.arms,R.drawable.back,R.drawable.chest,R.drawable.full,R.drawable.legs};
    String[] titles={"Abs","Arms","Back","Chest","full","legs"};
    for (int i=0; i<icons.length && i<titles.length;i++){

        Information current = new Information();
        current.images=icons[i];
        current.title=titles[i];
        data.add(current);
    }
    return data;

    }





    }
```

Comment: Try to use LinearLayout relative can be tricky.

Comment: how do you inflate the item layout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you are using `RecyclerView` and will make a **xml** file for list, in that case you have to use **`wrap_content`** as a height otherwise it will take height of device while you scrolled.

```
<LinearLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content">


<ImageView
   android:id="@+id/listicon"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="220dp />

    </LinearLayout>
```

in java do this :

```
recycler = (RecyclerView) layout.findViewById(R.id.recycler);
layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
recycler.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
adapter = new CustomAdapter(getActivity(), getData());
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: I tried your code, it sorted out my problem where there was problem when scrolling back up but there is this irregular space before and after a image and i can't figure it out ,

Comment: How to get rid of this space before and after image
1. https://ibb.co/hmS3K9
2. https://ibb.co/kUSg6p

Comment: @AmitNegi if your problem has been solved vote up and accept my answer it will help to other persons also if you do this

Comment: @AmitNegi mention full fragment.xml code and customlayout.xml code and java code also where you defined your recyclerview in onCreate method

Comment: @AmitNegi mention **fragment_home.xml** and **customlayout.xml** this one also full code of xml and I have updated the answer'

Comment: Tried it nothing changed

Comment: use Linear layout in fragment_home.xml  intead of frameLayout @AmitNegi

Comment: Still the same thing

Comment: @AmitNegi tell me actual problem what are you facing now

Comment: You see these gaps between images 
1. https://ibb.co/hmS3K9
2. https://ibb.co/bv3AGp
3. https://ibb.co/kUSg6p
I want to get rid of these

Comment: Bro, this problem will come when xml have some wrong parameters like : android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
   android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"

Comment: I removed it but nothing changes

Comment: do one thing and this is last i can tell you because i can not see what code you have written... do this uninstall app from device and clear project then rebuild then install again. @AmitNegi

Answer (score 0):

Adding this to my recycler view in fragment_home.xml did the trick

```
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
```